# [META] What's the difference between BrewAdvice and a forum?

Tags: meta

What makes BrewAdvice so cool? I can ask my questions on [HomebrewTalk](http://www.homebrewtalk.com/), [AHA Tech Talk](http://www.homebrewersassociation.org/pages/community/aha-forum), [ProBrewer](http://probrewer.com/), or the [HBD](http://hbd.org/).

Answer (score 3):

BrewAdvice is specifically for question and answer, rather than a discussion. If used properly, once a question has an answer, that question is "closed" and becomes a reference.

Forums are set up for more of a discussion format.

This system should allow for a much cleaner interface, with much better solution finding capabilities.

Comment: You failed to mention the lack of trolls and elitist ass-hats on a Q&A site like this.
Just sayin' ;)

Comment: It's still a young site...

Comment: This was supposed to be something of a troll.  Well, more like a softball question. (-:

Who's to say I am not an elitist ass-hat?

Comment: I'm very resilient to trolls. Bring it. ;)